# Opinions on budget amount for two months in Europe?

Tags: budget, europe, backpacking

I am planning a trip around Europe for around two months in the summer between June and August. I have a preliminary route planned:

- Starting **Scotland** --> June
- France
- Monte Carlo
- North Italy
- Slovenia
- Croatia
- Slovakia
- Austria
- Switzerland
- South Germany
- Czech Republic
- Poland
- North Germany
- Denmark
- Finland
- Sweden
- Norway
- -->Home **Scotland** - > Start of August approx.

I have a budget of £4,000 UK sterling / **€4,799.88**.

What are your opinions on this amount of money?

I won't be doing my trip hobo style and I won't be doing it like a prince. So lets say **61 days**, that's about €80/day.

This of course is not factoring in the Euro crisis and exchange rate?

In France and Switzerland I will be staying with friends and family and will spend more of my time out of the whole journey in those places, e.g. two weeks France, one week Switzerland. So that should reduce my accommodation outgoings.

In terms of travel costs, I will be planning to use Interrail or Eurorail.

I plan to just go walking about and take photographs!

Also how good is the Interrail card, I know it's not recognized by the French TGV. Are there any other train lines that don't recognize it?

[Here](http://www.tripline.net/trip/Eurotrip_Bruce-6031502460441004AB55F3DFBEB7A2DD?n=63) is my basic route for now. There is a video animation!

Comment: 2 months = 61 days, 4000 / 61 = £65 or about 78 Euros per day or average.

Comment: It really depends on your standards. If you want to stay in cheap hotels/hostels, not eating out all the time and be careful with your travel expenses, 78 euros a day are enough for most countries in your list. Expect maybe Switzerland, Denmark, Sweden and Norway. These countries are really expensive!

Comment: @loosebruce, welcome to Travel.SE.  Could you be more specific? When you say 'is it enough' - this is very subjective.  Is it enough to survive? Hobos manage, so yeah.  Is it enough to have fun? Whose standards? Perhaps describe if you want to stay in hostels, or hotels, what activities you want to do, festivals, whether you drink or not, and we can then objectively answer it for you.  How are you getting from Denmark to Finland since they aren't directly connected? Ferry? Etc.

Comment: @MarkMayo - sorry about this i accidently hit the enter button when writing my question and panicked , so

Comment: I have added more details!

Comment: I wish they had a confirm button on this site to stop you posting your question before finished :(

Comment: I'm also a bit worried this might come under what Stack Exchange calls "too localized". It seems very specific to your exact trip and might not be very useful to anybody else in the future the way it is now.

Comment: @hippietrail - i have made slight adjustments to make the question more general.

Comment: Looking better.  Don't panic, the community is here to help ;)

Comment: @hippietrail - Well, if there is a list of countries, others can always take info relevant to their trip and just read the rest, it won't hurt them. Posting specific countries in a question will certainly help getting more useful answers.

Comment: @loosebruce, I'm not worried about your funds, so much as the number of destinations, you're doing 38 'stops' in 61 days.  If there is a day travelling each time(not unreasonable) you may find you spend 70% of your time on trains buses and planes and very little time seeing stuff.

Comment: @Stuart - i am leaving August as a month I can use if i need to take more time however I would like to see most of my trip during the months of June and July and then I dont need to worry about getting home in August as my job starts in September :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With that budget, you won't have to "live like a hobo" but as other suggested, you do have to tell us what your interests are, do you want to go out drinking with friends or would you rather see the monuments and go to bed early, what you would accept as you accommodation, whether you'd like to eat at fast food joints or try country specific cuisine.

And without the itinerary, we can't help since different countries have different standards and prices.

That France and Switzerland family stay period will let you keep a lot of your money but then again, you would spend a lot of money in Scandinavian countries if you decided to go there.

Did you consider Baltic countries, Balkan countries or even Turkey?
Balkan countries are, for example, a lot cheaper than the Western Europe, especially Montenegro, Bosnia, Romania and Bulgaria. Even Serbia is quite cheap. I recommend homestays in Bosnia (very cheap, especially if you're not alone) and if you want to live like a king (or prince, as you say), go to Montenegro and stay in fancy hotels and enjoy the culture.

If we put France and Switzerland to the side, Spain, Portugal, Italy, Benelux are quite expensive but if you stay in hostels (and there are quite a few cheap cozy ones) and make bookings early enough, you should even have some spare money. Museum and monument tickets are expensive in all of the Europe so watch out for those. My opinion is, if you don't like something like modern art, don't visit modern art museums. Save that money and use it on something you enjoy more.

Yeah, traveling by train is your best option as it is cheap and fun but I wouldn't suggest an Interrail pass if you stay at certain countries for a long time since it's too expensive then. Use country specific passes if you want to travel a lot inside a specific country and if you want to go from one country to another, check the price for a single ticket(s) and compare it to the price of Interrail passes (either 175 euros for a `5 days travel within 10 days` or 257 euros for a `10 days travel within 22 days`) and then choose a better option.

**UPDATE:**

Let's see:
*France* - no accommodation costs and you'll eat at home a lot but you will most likely go out in the evenings and you'll be visiting museums and so on so you would probably need 50 to 60 euros a day, although, if you just take evening walks through the town, go for a drink or two, you could spend as low as 15 euros, especially if you take photographs. Being a photographer really helps your budget because you don't take track of the time and it's bed time sooner than you'd think.

*Monte Carlo* - I presume you will be only passing through it so count on spending maybe 30 euros there for a meal, a drink and maybe some souvenirs.

*Italy* - I don't particularly like North Italy, it's crowded, people aren't friendly and are always trying to scam you and everything is way more expensive for the foreigners. 70 to 80 euros a day if you stay in a hostel that isn't in the strict center of the cities. For things like ice cream, drinks or cheap meals, ask the locals if they seem likely to help. Take photos of famous sights but aim for parts of the towns that aren't visible to everyone, there's a bunch of small alleys for you to explore.

*Slovenia* - Not that expensive but you'll be probably only passing through since it's small. Check out Ljubljana, Maribor or Bled. If you're not staying for the night - 30 euros, if you are - 45-55.

*Croatia* - Also, not as expensive as western Europe. Hostels are 15-25 euros a night, eating for a day + one museum a day - 20-25 euros. Here's a patriot in me speaking but you really should visit our coast (you are coming in the summer time, right?), you will love it. There's a lot of festivals, clubs etc. for you to enjoy. And you can even get to Montenegro if you follow the coast to the south. Visit Zagreb, [Pula amphitheatre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pula_Arena), [Split palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocletian%27s_Palace) and [Dubrovnik Walls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walls_of_Dubrovnik).

*Hungary* - Don't know that much about it so I won't comment really but I think you should be fine with 60-70 euros a day.

*Slovakia/Czech Republic* - I shouldn't be putting them together but they are so damn similar. You can get cheap drinks in both, have a lot of monuments to visit, both are quite nice and also not that expensive but will probably be a bit more expensive than they usually are because of the Euro 2012 that's in June, taking place in Poland which is right next to them. I believe it should be 40-60 euros a day depending on what you want to do. Take note that a lot of great sights/monuments in these countries (Poland as well) are not really close to bigger cities so you'd have to pay bus tickets for day trips.

*Poland* - I'm going there in June and then I'm going to Czech Republic after that. Be sure that it will be quite expensive because of the Football Euro Championship. I believe 70-80 euros a day will be enough but make sure you book your hostel early.

*Austria* - Austria is always nice but since summer is off season, you'll get good deals on everything, from hostels to food. 60 euros a day at max.

Also, do tell what you want to see and do so that I can reference that in my answer.

**UPDATE 2:**

*Switzerland* I've never been but my Mom has and she was smitten. She did visit it in the winter months but it's suppose to be nice all year round. It's a bit more expensive than rest of the West Europe but you can count on spending the same amount as in France since you're staying with you friends.

*Germany* I haven't been to Germany as a tourist, just passing through and went to a music festival once so can't really comment on that. I don't think you'd have to spend more than 60 euros a day.

*Denmark/Sweden/Norway/Finland* Very expensive for tourists. Hostels are almost always amazing but are about 30-35 euros per night (in a dorm). Food is great, especially fish dishes but is expensive as well. You'll probably spend the largest amount of money here but you can always shorten the trip since it would be your last leg. You probably won't use all of it but put 100 euros a day for these countries. Also, you must visit [Stockholm metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_metro), it's amazing!

Since you mentioned Soviet architecture, how about you visit Belgrade in Serbia? It has a lot of buildings similar to Soviet ones. BTW, why aren't you visiting Moscow? It is pretty expensive but two years ago, I visited it and got a hostel room for 6 people for 8 euros per person per day. The old [skyscrapers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Sisters_%28Moscow%29) are amazing and you would enjoy taking photos of them.

But don't worry, you'll be able to see that kind of architecture in Warsaw, Czech republic, Helsinki and a couple of other places as well...

BTW, when you get to Zagreb, check out metal bar [Runa](http://www.myspace.com/metalbarruna), a nice bar in the Upper town (the oldest part of the town).

That's it from me, if you have any other, more specific questions, create new questions and we'll answer them as soon as possible if we know the answers!

Comment: I will put the country list up again, I had to take it down because it was too specific scope. Thankyou for your wonderful help so far!

Comment: Updated once...

Comment: Thanks! I am not a drinker even though I am scottish lol so that will keep my costs down. I like photography and would prefer to be out in nature. I hear that Slovakia, Croatia have beautiful wildlife. I made this tripline animation to give you a more accurate idea.

Really appreciate your efforts and contribution!

Comment: http://www.tripline.net/trip/Eurotrip_Bruce-6031502460441004AB55F3DFBEB7A2DD?n=63

Comment: My interests are War stuff and Soviet architecture. I am not really interested in partying or staying out late and I prefer to get up really early in the morning and enjoy stuff before it gets busy :)

Comment: I like cars which is why I am going to Monte Carlo to see all the nice cars :)

Comment: I also like Heavy Metal and hopefully will check out some music from different areas

Comment: Updated twice... (I forgot to mention, if you want to take photos of wildlife in Croatia or Slovenia, create a question and I'll get back to you with some suggestions. Any other travel photography questions are welcome as well.)

Comment: Just a [preview of Croatia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plitvice_Lakes_National_Park).

Comment: Hungary(Budapest fairly central) 7 euro a night, the food is cheap and the servings are massive local restaurant 5euros for dinner and wine.

Comment: Great, thanks... That means 30 to 40 euros a day in Hungary.

Comment: Is Bosnia safe? I dont want to get blown up lol!

Comment: Completely safe... You have to try this [meat dish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86evapi) if you decide to go there. They're especially good in Sarajevo.